# How can we know the maximum of a scalar field after Lorentz transforamtion?

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory

Support that we have a field $\phi(x)$. we do the Lorentz transformation for it, namely,
$$
\phi(x) \to \phi'(x)= \phi(\Lambda^{-1}x).
$$
If the field $\phi(x)$ takes the maximum at point $x=a$, where does the field $\phi'(x)$ take the maximum at point x? From the Lorentz transformation, I think that at point $x=\Lambda^{-1} a$, the field $\phi'(x)$ takes the maximum. Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. What is $x$? Is it a space coordinate ? If yes, your question is without sense since the Lorentz transformation is applied on space-time coordinates.

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE! What you are writing seems legit, as long as by $x$ you denote a space-time coordinate, as @Frobenius is right...

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the transformation $x^{\mu}=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} x^{\nu}$ considering you are transforming four vector from one frame to another. Then the field's mode coordinates will be changed but the field itself will be invariant since proper time are connected by Lorentz transformations.